# How can I pass directory identifier to an action in Install Shield

Tags: iis-7, installshield, command-prompt, appcmd

I tried to add an directory identifier direcly to an command prompt action:

[image: Pass directory identifier]

My Setup runs into an Error using this command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
/physicalPaath:"[INSTALLDIR]\"
```

It is important to use the backslash at the end.